# "economic burden" VS. "financial burden"--are they interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice

I am wondering if these two phrases are interchangeable in context like the example sentences below.

1. Buying a house often places a huge financial burden on young couples.
   Buying a house often places a huge economic burden on young couples.
2. Studying abroad adds financial burden to family.
   Studying abroad adds economic burden to family.

Comment: They are synonyms when “economic” is used in the financial sense.

Answer (score 1):

In almost all contexts, the two terms are interchangeable.

There are, however, some contexts in which, in considering the economic costs (burdens) of something, one wants to take into account not only the burdens of paying for it, but all the burdens that can be measured in economic terms, including those that don't involve actual payments. To develop the OP's example, suppose that some plumbing repairs need to be carried out on the young couple's house, and that a plumber would charge £100 for that work. To save the money, the owners do the work themselves. Their work has a definite value, expressible in economic terms, that is £100, even though it was not paid for. In such a case it can be said that the £100, the economic value of the work they have done, is a part of the economic burden of having the house, even though it is not a part of the financial burden.

Again, the significance of all this is likely to be appreciated only in certain theoretical contexts. Most young couples simply ignore the economic value of the burdens such as doing plumbing repairs on their own. In most everyday contexts, *financial burdens* and *economic burdens* are thus interchangeable.

Comment: A good answer (+1), but there are many more possible contexts here. Anything, for example, that involves **externalities**. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/externality.asp

Comment: @GlobalCharm, yes, the burdens of something can include its externalities, and these burdens are very often economic (in the sense outlined here), but not financial. The OP's second example might arguably be about externalities, depending on whether we think of the student's family as external to the transaction, or we think of the whole family as directly involved in sending the student abroad.